# Локализация интерфейса голосования

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Интерфейс голосования нуждается в переводе следующих сообщений

- Your ballot
- Selections saved
- Drag and drop or click your selections in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate as first choice. You do not need to rank all candidates.
- Unranked candidates will not receive your vote.
- (Drag next selection here)
- Pending save in {seconds}
- Clear all
- (All candidates have been selected)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Переводы добавлены в traducir, подхватятся с новой сборкой. Т.е. скорее всего только в понедельник.

Текущая 2023.4.14.43390